# Why does log4j create the logfile in my Java application but not in my web application?

Tags: java, web-applications, log4j

I have tested this configuration

```
# Define the root logger with appender file
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, CONSOLE, FILE

# CONSOLE appender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Threshold=debug

# FILE appender
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n

# Set the name of the file
log4j.appender.FILE.File=/home/user/annotator-log.out

# Set the immediate flush to true (default)
log4j.appender.FILE.ImmediateFlush=true

# Set the threshold to debug mode
log4j.appender.FILE.Threshold=info

# Set the append to false, overwrite
log4j.appender.FILE.Append=false
```

using this simple `Main.java`

```
package playground;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class Main {

    private final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName());

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LOGGER.info("Running main ..");

        LOGGER.debug("Reading args:");

        for (String arg : args) {
            LOGGER.debug("    " + arg);
        }       

        LOGGER.info("All done.");
    }

}
```

and it works. The logging gets printed to the console and the file gets created at `/home/user/annotator-log.out`

However, if I put the `.properties` file into my web application I can only see the output in the console but the log file is not getting created.

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Where are you putting the .properties file. Are you mentioning in your web.xml that your web app needs to use the log4j.propertie file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting this in your web.xml.

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>log4j-config-location</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/log4j.properties</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

Comment: Make sure your log4j.properties is under web-inf folder

Comment: That was it. I thought it's enough if the file is available in the classpath - but it makes sense of course to put it somewhere in the web application ..

Answer (score 0):

Programatic solution:

```
String log4jPropertiesFilePath = ...;
org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure(log4jPropertiesFilePath);
```

We use it when we only can know file location at runtime!